Placement behavior of el-dropdown
I am using the dropdown component from the Element UI library in Vue. The documentation can be found here: https://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/dropdown#dropdown
I have already set placement="top" on the el-dropdown.
The dropdown appears at the above of the element as expected. However, sometimes I notice that the dropdown appears below the element, even when there is enough space above to display it.
I would like to ask: what conditions does Element UI use to determine whether the dropdown appears above or below the element? Do we have any way to fixed it always show on top?

All i know is that dropdown element use popper.js behind the scenes. I haven't tried it, but you should be able to pass popper.js option in dropdown element API. And the popper.js have flip option that you can set to false. Hope this helps
